# What is ISqlProviderSecuritySettings property in implementing Dynamic WCF authorization?

Tags: sql, wcf, dynamic, authorization, roleprovider

In the below url, dynamic WCF authorization is explained.

[Implementing Dynamic Authorization for a WCF service using SQL providers](http://blogs.technet.com/b/meamcs/archive/2011/05/12/implementing-dynamic-authorization-for-a-wcf-service-using-sql-providers.aspx)

But the property **ISqlProviderSecuritySettings** is not recognized by .Net framework.
Please help on this.